# Assign values to python list specific position

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am newbie in Python and maybe my problem is very simple.

I have created a list of 250 zeros called *x*, `x = np.zeros(250)`, and I have a loop where I perform some calculations, at each iteration I produce two x's for example in the first iteration the x[0] and x[1] and so on in a list called temp_x. i.e., the first temp_x has the x[0] and x[1]

I want to save the output at the end of each iteration to the corresponding positions of the x. For example at the end of the first iteration temp_x has two values I want to assign them to the first positions of x.

What I am doing wrong?

```
x[i, i+1] = x_temp
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine
`x[i] = x[i+1] = x_temp`

Comment: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Apparently numpy creates not a list but a `numpy.ndarray` object with `np.zeros()` call, I haven't worked with it much but it still worked for me in REPL

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in @IAmVisco's answer, chained assignment will work.

However, to go into the reason your code doesn't:

When you type something like `x[i, i+1]`, Python understands the value in the square brackets as a `tuple`, and therefore actually attempts to execute `x[(i, i + 1)]`, which accesses the element at row `i` and column `i + 1`. Since there is no such element (`x` is a 1D array), it fails with the error "too many indices for array".

If you actually want to access two (or more) elements in that way, your indices should be in a form of a `np.ndarray` (a `list` would work too):

```
>>> x = np.ones(10)
>>> x[np.array([0, 1])] = 2
>>> x
array([2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: It does not even have to be a numpy array, just a list. `x[[0, 1]] = 2` will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure IAmVisco's answer will do what is required, it will instead set both of the elements of x to the list x_temp.

What I think you need instead is:

```
x[i], x[i+1] = x_temp
```

This unpacks each element of `x_temp` into each element of `x`